# How to generate a random number from a user defined discrete uniform distribution in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Imagine that I have written the following code in Matlab.

```
numItems = 100 ;
Levels = [0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]
prob = [.25, .25, .25, .25] 
% prob can be any set of probability values.
```

I want to generate a discrete uniform distribution with values `Levels` for a vector of `numItems` elements considering the values of `prob`.

If I simply explain, I need to do something similar to **np.random.choice** in Numpy.
I tried with **unirnd** but it is only possible with positive integers by not floating-point numbers.

Can anyone please help me with this?
Thanks.

Comment: do you only use it for this example where all prob values are the same, or is this suppose to be any value as long as they sum up to 1?

Comment: @bla It can be any set of values which ultimately sum up to 1.